# R Vector not Accepted

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I am entering two vectors manually like this:

```
seqA<-c(-11.742,-1.551,1.308,27.407,47.636,40.457,40.457,44.574,24.345,-7.879,-14.461,-18.577,-7.751,-8.259,-1.677,-0.355,-8.776,-8.268,-25.417,-23.801,-15.380,21.845,42.073,40.457,40.457,47.636,27.407,1.308,17.538,10.359,54.563,67.731,51.501,1.173,-9.114,-22.282,-18.866,-8.115,2.172,40.830,57.634,46.884,20.334,17.809,1.004,-11.104,-0.201,2.324,41.286,63.263,52.361,35.548,36.336,14.359,-11.207,1.961,1.173,51.501,70.743,57.575,19.396,20.859,1.617,4.237,15.738,14.274,31.729,61.010,49.509,67.613,82.489,53.209,6.298,5.921,-8.956,7.448,13.125,13.502,9.206,7.013,1.336,-10.109,5.099,7.293,53.541,66.709,51.501,1.173,-5.409,-18.577,-7.751,1.779,8.361,29.758,50.607,41.077,42.317,56.964,36.116,22.472,50.634,35.987,76.662,102.299,74.137,28.410,26.861,1.225,-7.420,-14.313,-12.765,-14.809,-22.725,-15.832,-15.832,-4.750,3.166,41.162,55.617,44.535,13.286,8.412,-6.043,-13.453,-10.957,-6.083,16.067,32.967,30.471,37.128,51.155,34.255,21.852,17.266,3.239,-21.581,-19.345,-14.759,23.705,33.855,31.619,8.981,18.511,8.361,29.758,55.064,45.534,55.689,81.615,56.309,47.395,53.840,27.914,-2.134,-7.008,-13.453,-6.043,-4.863,0.011,4.709,25.640,24.460,59.263,97.595,76.665,76.665,95.246,56.914,17.413,18.593,0.011,4.709,25.640,24.460,59.263,74.471,53.541,7.293,10.120,-5.088,16.398,33.918,31.091,38.989,49.800,32.280,10.964,21.155,10.344,30.419,39.949,29.758,8.361,11.689,2.159,11.153,16.830,13.502,9.206,7.013,1.336,-10.109,1.125,3.318,41.617,52.520,41.286,2.324,-10.464,-21.366,-29.783,-23.090,-10.302,37.077,59.054,52.361,35.548,61.500,39.522,64.284,82.865,56.914,17.413,12.539,-6.043,-13.453,-7.628,-2.754,26.053,46.902,41.077,42.317,56.964,36.116,22.472,17.886,3.239,-21.581,-30.664,-26.078,-10.252,8.330,17.413,56.914,86.194,67.613,49.509,69.737,40.457,40.457,46.613,26.385,-1.759,-5.641,-11.797,-3.728,-12.149,-8.268,-25.417,-42.413,-33.992,-33.992,-32.376,-15.380,21.845,29.023,27.407,1.308,-3.348,-10.527,-8.096,5.224,9.879,43.399,62.351,49.032,26.777,24.692,5.740,-14.080,-20.001,-17.916,-5.768,-7.411,-1.490,-5.084,-5.039,-3.396,3.574,5.415,5.370,1.994,12.185,10.344,30.419,55.573,45.382,55.234,74.186,49.032,26.777,22.192,3.239,-21.581,-19.345,-14.759,23.705,30.150,27.914,-2.134,4.311,-2.134,27.914,34.690,28.245,-1.139,10.095,3.318,41.617,50.811,39.577,-2.801,-17.297,-26.491,-31.491,-48.487,-33.992,-33.992,-23.324,-6.328,49.000,81.201,70.532,58.268,71.379,39.179,13.264,20.126,7.015,20.433,37.333,30.471,37.128,62.434,45.534,55.689,74.793,49.488,26.929,55.091,35.987,76.662,96.623,68.461,11.382,8.857,-11.104,1.004,-0.166,2.358,-7.042,-14.267,-13.096,-15.804,-5.053,2.172,40.830,47.372,36.621,-10.454,-15.040,-21.581,3.239,8.916,13.502,9.206,10.386,4.709,0.011,1.191,0.011,4.709,6.551,5.370,1.994,-2.218,-4.060,-12.792,-6.347,-2.134,27.914,34.359,27.914,-2.134,4.311,-2.134,27.914,34.690,28.245,-1.139,5.637,-1.139,28.245,36.044,29.268,1.928,9.726,1.928,29.268,55.194,47.395,56.309,68.566,42.640,6.385,-2.258,-14.514,-20.058,-25.689,-17.046,-5.478,-9.359,-3.728,-11.797,-0.563,3.318,41.617,53.873,42.640,6.385,-2.548,-14.804,-20.928,-7.760,1.173,51.501,72.054,58.885,23.326,21.778,1.225,-7.420,-18.854,-17.305,-28.429,-21.888,-10.454,36.621,51.077,44.535,13.286,8.412,-6.043,-13.453,-7.628,-2.754,26.053,30.170,24.345,-7.879,5.290,1.173,51.501,70.082,56.914,17.413,10.830,-7.751,-18.577,-33.073,-26.491,-31.491,-39.913,-25.417,-8.268,-12.149,-3.728,-11.797,-21.753,-17.871,-21.951,-21.163,-11.207,14.359,22.909,22.121,12.079,7.846,-0.704,-16.228,-28.224,-23.991,-23.991,-26.076,-14.080,5.740,24.844,26.929,49.488,60.390,41.286,2.324,4.820,-6.083,16.067,33.587,31.091,38.989,73.973,56.453,83.484,101.737,66.752,6.257,15.451,-2.801,39.577,50.480,41.286,2.324,-10.464,-21.366,-29.783,-27.547,-14.759,23.705,34.516,32.280,10.964,30.207,19.396,57.575,87.475,68.233,51.369,63.868,33.968,16.028,19.558,7.059,7.059,10.588,7.059,7.059,8.900,5.370,1.994,17.111,15.270,45.196,60.312,45.196,15.270,26.081,10.964,32.280,41.294,30.483,5.574,-2.144,-11.158,-19.713,-14.976,-7.259,26.206,34.004,29.268,1.928,9.106,1.308,27.407,47.636,40.457,40.457,60.685,40.457,40.457,65.763,45.534,55.689,70.297,44.991,13.438,32.020,17.413,56.914,77.467,58.885,23.326,39.905,19.352,46.962,77.345,60.767,60.767,71.669,41.286,2.324,1.947,-8.956,7.448,5.363,5.740,-14.080,-16.166,-14.080,5.740,11.417,13.502,9.206,21.085,15.408,32.107,49.007,37.128,30.471,37.333,20.433,7.015,1.094,-5.768,-17.916,-27.872,-21.951,-17.871,-6.637,3.318,41.617,56.224,44.991,13.438,14.618,0.011,4.709,-2.024,-3.204,-23.729,-17.035,-10.302,37.077,67.309,60.615,60.311,71.393,41.162,3.166,-5.081,-16.163,-16.826,-22.836,-14.588,-9.450,-4.385,1.625,18.636,35.536,30.471,37.128,42.953,26.053,-2.754,12.123,6.298,53.209,91.541,76.665)

seqB<-c(-11.742,-1.551,1.308,27.407,35.801,28.623,4.954,-2.764,-11.158,-19.713,-23.946,-16.228,-0.704,2.448,6.681,5.925,6.727,3.576,-0.367,14.088,13.286,44.535,69.689,55.234,45.382,52.561,27.407,1.308,17.538,10.359,54.563,67.731,51.501,1.173,-9.114,-22.282,-18.866,-8.115,2.172,40.830,57.634,46.884,20.334,17.809,1.004,-11.104,-0.201,2.324,41.286,63.263,52.361,35.548,36.336,14.359,-11.207,1.961,1.173,51.501,70.743,57.575,19.396,20.859,1.617,4.237,15.738,14.274,31.729,61.010,49.509,67.613,82.489,53.209,6.298,5.921,-8.956,7.448,13.125,13.502,9.206,8.035,2.358,-7.042,9.188,10.359,54.563,77.641,61.411,30.903,34.231,11.153,2.159,11.689,8.361,29.758,50.607,41.077,42.317,56.964,36.116,22.472,50.634,35.987,76.662,96.623,68.461,11.382,4.157,-15.804,-13.096,-19.990,-12.765,-14.809,-21.703,-14.809,-12.765,-0.660,6.233,42.184,56.639,44.535,13.286,8.412,-6.043,-13.453,-10.957,-6.083,16.067,32.967,30.471,37.128,51.155,34.255,21.852,17.266,3.239,-21.581,-19.345,-14.759,23.705,33.855,31.619,8.981,18.511,8.361,29.758,55.064,45.534,55.689,81.615,56.309,47.395,53.840,27.914,-2.134,-7.008,-13.453,-6.043,-2.715,2.159,11.153,14.481,11.153,2.159,20.740,17.413,56.914,75.495,56.914,17.413,18.593,0.011,4.709,25.640,24.460,59.263,74.471,53.541,7.293,10.120,-5.088,16.398,33.918,31.091,38.989,49.800,32.280,10.964,21.155,10.344,30.419,39.949,29.758,8.361,1.779,-7.751,-18.577,-22.810,-16.228,-0.704,-2.897,1.336,-10.109,1.125,3.318,41.617,52.520,41.286,2.324,-10.464,-21.366,-29.783,-23.090,-10.302,37.077,59.054,52.361,35.548,61.500,39.522,64.284,85.215,59.263,24.460,21.935,1.004,-11.104,-5.279,-2.754,26.053,46.902,41.077,42.317,56.964,36.116,22.472,17.886,3.239,-21.581,-30.664,-26.078,-10.252,8.330,17.413,56.914,86.194,67.613,49.509,74.663,45.382,55.234,67.338,42.184,6.233,3.374,-8.730,-2.706,-11.127,-8.268,-25.417,-32.528,-24.107,-4.338,7.163,14.274,31.729,38.908,27.407,1.308,-3.348,-10.527,-8.096,5.224,9.879,43.399,62.351,49.032,26.777,24.692,5.740,-14.080,-20.001,-17.916,-5.768,-7.411,-1.490,-5.084,-5.039,-3.396,3.574,5.415,5.370,1.994,-1.887,-3.728,-11.797,-0.715,3.166,41.162,60.114,49.032,26.777,22.192,3.239,-21.581,-19.345,-14.759,23.705,30.150,27.914,-2.134,4.311,-2.134,27.914,34.690,28.245,-1.139,10.095,3.318,41.617,50.811,39.577,-2.801,-17.297,-26.491,-31.491,-48.487,-33.992,-33.992,-23.324,-6.328,49.000,69.931,59.263,24.460,26.301,5.370,1.994,8.856,7.015,20.433,37.333,30.471,37.128,62.282,45.382,55.234,74.186,49.032,26.777,54.940,35.987,76.662,96.623,68.461,11.382,6.508,-13.453,-6.043,-10.917,-6.043,-13.453,-22.032,-17.158,-17.158,-6.255,2.324,41.286,47.979,37.077,-10.302,-19.385,-26.078,-10.252,-14.794,-5.711,-12.458,-6.302,-1.759,26.385,36.576,30.419,10.344,10.497,0.306,0.306,-3.906,-4.060,-12.792,-6.347,-2.134,27.914,34.359,27.914,-2.134,4.311,-2.134,27.914,53.840,47.395,56.309,82.236,56.309,47.395,55.194,29.268,1.928,14.184,6.385,42.640,76.997,64.741,72.690,88.921,54.563,10.359,3.466,-12.765,-14.809,-19.352,-12.458,-5.711,-10.585,-6.043,-13.453,-2.550,2.324,41.286,52.520,41.617,3.318,-6.637,-17.871,-21.951,-8.782,1.173,51.501,72.054,58.885,23.326,21.778,1.225,-7.420,-18.854,-17.305,-28.429,-21.888,-10.454,36.621,51.077,44.535,13.286,14.466,0.011,4.709,7.861,6.681,5.925,22.351,19.200,46.506,72.280,55.854,47.243,56.257,30.483,5.574,7.766,-1.248,10.017,14.006,11.814,4.142,3.634,-0.355,-1.677,-0.497,0.011,4.709,0.476,-0.704,-16.228,-15.440,-11.207,14.359,16.855,16.067,-6.083,-10.296,-12.792,-4.060,6.131,10.344,30.419,41.920,31.729,14.274,15.738,4.237,1.617,20.859,19.396,57.575,72.452,53.209,6.298,8.794,-6.083,16.067,33.587,31.091,38.989,68.889,51.369,68.233,81.401,51.501,1.173,10.367,-2.801,39.577,53.049,43.855,10.031,7.727,-5.745,-3.474,6.676,8.981,31.619,42.430,32.280,10.964,30.207,19.396,57.575,75.021,55.778,14.006,6.288,-11.158,-19.713,-23.946,-16.228,-0.704,-3.229,1.004,-11.104,-15.316,-12.792,-4.060,6.131,10.344,30.419,40.610,30.419,10.344,21.155,10.964,32.280,41.294,30.483,5.574,-2.144,-11.158,-19.713,-14.976,-7.259,26.206,34.004,29.268,1.928,9.106,1.308,27.407,47.636,40.457,40.457,60.685,40.457,40.457,65.763,45.534,55.689,70.297,44.991,13.438,32.020,17.413,56.914,77.467,58.885,23.326,39.905,19.352,46.962,77.345,60.767,60.767,70.251,39.868,-1.931,-3.726,-13.210,6.030,3.945,5.740,-14.080,-16.166,-14.080,5.740,11.417,13.502,9.206,21.085,15.408,32.107,49.007,37.128,30.471,37.333,20.433,7.015,1.094,-5.768,-17.916,-27.872,-21.951,-17.871,-25.787,-15.832,-15.832,-20.374,-12.458,-5.711,-4.531,0.011,4.709,2.185,1.004,-11.104,-0.201,2.324,41.286,66.592,55.689,45.534,51.691,26.385,-1.759,-10.007,-16.163,-16.826,-25.073,-16.826,-16.163,-13.335,-5.088,16.398,33.298,30.471,37.128,42.953,26.053,-2.754,12.123,6.298,53.209,91.541,76.665)
```

I then execute the code and I get the error:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"
seqB"
```

I have tried this with shorter vectors and I have had no problem.  I have also used the MSWord Find function to search for aberrant characters and have found none.  How can I get R to take this vector?

Comment: I ran it without any problem

Comment: I am running R version 4.0.5.  What version are you running @ThomasIsCoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your error.
There is a limit for input into the R console: it cannot exceed 4095 bytes (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#R-commands_003b-case-sensitivity-etc)).

You can fix your error by splitting the vectors across multiple lines.

Also note, this error doesn't occur if you source a file with these really long lines in them, it only occurs when you run the command in the console.